# How can I pretty print truncated JSON?

Tags: json, posix, pretty-print

I want to pretty print the first part of an enormous JSON file, but the truncation breaks python's json.tool prettifier. How would I print the truncated JSON readably?

```
$ head -c 1000 "myfile.json" > tmp
$ python -m json.tool "myfile.json"
Unterminated string starting at: line 1 column 975 (char 974)
```

So for the JSON file:

```
{"cat":{"limbs":["foreleg":...],...},...}
```

I would pretty print the first fifteen characters as:

```
{
    "cat": {
        "limbs"
```

Comment: can you "print" it to a variable and then only actually display a small amount of that string?

Comment: If the file is very large and has no newlines that will not work. Or rather, it will, but will consume a ton of memory and take a long time. I want to print the beginning only, without waiting for it to load the whole thing every time.

Comment: possibly that could be an issue, true. how large are you expecting the files to be? And also I'm wondering why exactly you need to just display part of it?

Comment: The files average larger then 200 Mb, and may become much larger. I want to be able to perform a quick and shallow integrity and format verification, much like you would when using `head myfile.txt`. If you tried to do this with a 250 Mb JSON file that has no newlines, your terminal will be flooded with illegible junk.

Comment: you can't verify the integrity of JSON without analysing the whole structure - just because the first few lines are ok doesn't mean there aren't things missing later that would break it. You might be better to write/use something that will actually verify that the JSON is really valid. If you want to look for specific items within the data, you'd have to customise it to traverse the data, but it looks like there are some tools / ideas out there already for general verification: https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=python%20check%20valid%20json

Comment: I am aware that you cannot verify syntactic integrity without scanning the whole file, that was not my intention and there are readily available tools for that. The goal was to have a way for a human to quickly peek into a dense and large json file quickly.